# EF Core - multiple counts in one sql request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get multiple count stats from a table but I'm not getting what I want.

**Code**

```
var result = _db.Users.Select(g => new
{
    count = _db.Users.Count(),
    acCount = _db.Users.Count(u => u.User.State == AccountState.AwaitingConfirmation)
});
```

**Sql request**

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `users` AS `c`
) AS `count`, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `users` AS `u`
    INNER JOIN `users` AS `u.User` ON `u`.`UserId` = `u.User`.`Id`
    WHERE `u.User`.`State` = 4
) AS `acCount`
FROM `users` AS `g`
```

**Expected Result**

```
result = { count = ?, acCount = ? }
```

**Actual Result (4 users in the table)**

```
result = [
    { count = ?, acCount = ? },
    { count = ?, acCount = ? },
    { count = ?, acCount = ? },
    { count = ?, acCount = ? }
]
```

Obviously this is wrong because I am using `Select` which gives me the counts N times (N being the number of rows in the users table).
What I want is to be able to get these counts directly and once, preferably in one request.

I also tried `GroupBy(i => 1)` but that gives A LOT of sql requests..

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the expected result more clearly? I.e., please explain a bit more about the problem itself and what you want to get exactly (I did not get exactly what you want to get).

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: So you want to to add each `count` value to the previous one?

Comment: I need 2 counts, my query gives me 2 counts * the number of rows in the table.

Comment: group by constant (1) technique works (I mean, with single SQL) in the latest EF Core 2.1 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916302/groupby-query-and-bit-fields/50916931#50916931

Comment: I tried the same syntax but it's weird, the same sql request gets executed 3 times, why?...

Comment: What **exact** EF Core version are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev 2.1 (Pamelo)

Comment: Then you should be ok (with [2.1 provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/2.1.0-rc1-final)). See the end of the updated answer of Chirag Rupani, referring to my comment, I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query is being executed for each row of the user due to `_db.Users.Select` statement.

You can use below query to get only counts from tables:

```
var counts = new {
    count = _db.Users.Count(),
    acCount = _db.Users.Count(u => u.User.State == AccountState.AwaitingConfirmation)
};
```

To get both counts in single query - as mentioned in the comments (notice using flag to identify awaiting confirmation and grouping by constants and then using sum to get count based on the flag):

```
  var counts = 
     _db.Users
    .Select(e => new { AwaitingConfirmation = 
             u.User.State == AccountState.AwaitingConfirmation ? 1 : 0 })
    .GroupBy(e => 1)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Count = g.Count(),
        account = g.Sum(e => e.AwaitingConfirmation)
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Using this with `First` gives counts with maximum of 1.

Comment: Anyway I ended up using `.ToArray()[0]` as ugly as it is.