# Dapper-like Multi Query with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework

With dapper it is pretty easy to run mulitple queries in one run:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}))
    {
        var invoice = multi.Read<Invoice>().First();
        var invoiceItems = multi.Read<InvoiceItem>().ToList();
    }
}
```

How to archieve this with EFCore?

I found solutions like

```
var query = from _ in db.Invoices
            select new {
                Invoice = db.Invoices.Single(x=>x.InvoiceId == 1),
                InvoiceItems = db.InvoiceItems.Where(x=>x.InvoiceId == 1),
            }
```

but this does not work.
I can see in the profiling this runs two queries in two connections. I can even see that the connection is not reused (why?).

How to run multiple queries with EFCore is this a big performance-lack of EFCore?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care whether it's one batch or two?  Why not use eager loading: eg `db.Invoces.Include(i => i.InvoiceItems).Where(i => InvoiceId ==1);`

Comment: You are right, the sample here was not the best. The question should be interpreted as "how to run multiple queries against the same or not the same table". I have multiple purposes like multiple counts. But solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114437/ef-core-multiple-counts-in-one-sql-request dont work with EFCore because there is no mapping for GroupBy in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: MultiActiveResults was false.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

You are currently looking for the `Query Future` feature: https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-future

This feature is often called `Future` since all query will be materialized when the first immediate action will be executed such as `ToList`

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

// CREATE a pending list of future queries
var futureCountries = ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();
var futureStates = ctx.States.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();

// TRIGGER all pending queries in one database round trip
// SELECT * FROM Country WHERE IsActive = true;
// SELECT * FROM State WHERE IsActive = true
var countries = futureCountries.ToList();

// futureStates is already resolved and contains the result
var states = futureStates.ToList();
```

Online Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gwESn

**EDIT: Answer Comment**

> But async is not supported

Sure async is supported, any immediate method is supported such as `ToListAsync()`.

However, make sure the first immediate method as been fully executed (using `await` for example).

Comment: Could be nice for some situations, yes. But async is not supported? Cannot find a hint in your docs.

Comment: I gave your Lib a try and decided to dont use it.
The lib lacks simple things like async support, transaction parameters etc. A great advantage is FromQueryAsync, but unfortunately it totally disregards the paradigm of EF Core. It would be great, if you would get more in line here :-)